# How do you create validations for ModelForm in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble getting my validations to show up. First of all I am wondering if these validations should be done in models.py or forms.py?

Through research I found that you can create a validation using cleaned_data along with validation logic. I also found something called a validator that can be used in the model --and maybe modelForm too?

Here is some code that I have written where I don't see the validation in the view. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category= forms.ChoiceField(choices= CATEGORIES)
    service_description= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    more_service_info= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service_name', 'category', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode',
                'phone', 'website_link', 'service_description', 'more_service_info',
                'price', 'pub_date',)

    def clean_service_description(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['service_description']
        if len(data) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Description should be greater than 10 characters")
            return data
```

**EDIT** Here is my view code

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form= ServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            service_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            service_obj.user_id = request.user.id
            service_obj.save()

            return render_to_response('services/service_created.html', 
                              {'service': Service.objects.get(id=service_obj.id)})
    else:
        form = ServiceForm()

    args= {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('services/create_service.html', args )
```

Comment: There are two kind of validation method, as you mentioned. Validator is something build-in by django and can be applied in models. The other one is the validation method (or clean method) which should be performed in forms. For your case, rather than seeing the validation show up, I am more wondering whether your clean_* method get called or not

Comment: Thank you for the input. How do I call the clean method?

Comment: well that is easy. Valid your form inside your view. I assume you can do yourform.is_valid() to trigger the clean method.

Comment: Yes, I do. I can post my view code. I don't get any validation

Comment: if the you are sending POST request, which means form.is_valid() will be executed, it will make no sense that your validation method is got called. What I can think of is that you can try to make sure your other validation get called. Especially, try to add clean() method, and inside that check if you even get 'service_description' in the cleaned_data.